# Linux Local Server for offline 1 application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-applications, offline, ubuntu-server

I have an idea to build a web-app. I would like to run this web-app **offline** on 1 PC. But I would like a DB with it to store data.

So, I would like to make it so, you just boot up the PC (running on Linux), and it just boots the webapp and the server (maybe make it so you can't get out of the browser if that's possible).

So, I was thinking about taking an old PC, install Ubuntu server on it, and then modify it, so it directly boots the browser (going to the web-app) and the server on booting up the PC.

Can this work? Do I need ubuntu Server? Or can I just run a normal Linux Destro with a LAMP on it and let that boot when booting up.

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

No need for some special OS. Choose any distro you like, install XAMMP on it and put all the files your web page has inside htdocs folder. XAMPP is all ready to manage databases and FTP. Once set up, go to your browser at 127.0.0.1/route_to_the_htdocs_folder/yourstartpage.html. Hope that works for you!